# Regex and URLs in results

Tags: regex

I have a regex that grabs info from a reference site. Some of the facts have links and it doesn't grab the link. How can I achieve this?

The URL is  http://www.nationalpastime.com/

Here is my regex.

```
(?<=<td width="400">\s)[^<]+
```

Comment: Requisite "parsing HTML with regex" article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^t]|<\/t[^d]|<\/td[^>])+` instead of `[^<]`